# General bulk update for admin panel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, bulk, generalization

I'm using my own admin panel for my website and would like to introduce some bulk actions using http://railscasts.com/episodes/52-update-through-checkboxes. First of all, is this still best practice to do bulk actions?

Secondly, how can I generalize this piece of code so every controller in the admin panel can use it?

Looking forward to hearing your ideas!

Comment: First of all `update_all` does not trigger `validations` so it is  not recommended to use it and skip validations unnecessarily..if the field do not have validations then you can try `update_all`

Comment: You're right actually, I wonder why Ryan Bates would use it anyway? Any suggestion about the problem itself?

Comment: No one any suggestions?